# How to add library in Xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode8

I want to add [library](https://github.com/cheind/dest) to my iOS application in Xcode 8.3.

I've read a tutorial and so, I created a target 'DEST', after add this item in Target Dependencies and libDEST.a in Link Binary With Libraries. Also, I moved all forked library in project. Now, I'm trying to use this library as in example from git, but code doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you creating a bridging header to import your libDEST into the Swift context?  I am assuming this is a Swift project?

Comment: No, Objective-C project

Comment: Have you added `#include <dest/dest.h>` at the top of the .m file where you would like to use the library? What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Yes. There is no error with including <dest/dest.h>, but when I'm trying to use it like in an example `dest::core::Tracker t;` there is an error: "use of undeclared identifier dest"